# Use search with Linq in the stored procedure result performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, entity-framework, linq

I use a SQL stored procedure to retrieve all data from a big table and then use Linq to filter some data.

For example :

```
var listResult = myService.spGetAllData(param1,param2).ToList();
listResult = listResult.Where(x => x.Column1.Contains("something")).ToList();
```

I nee to know if it has a bad effect in performance or its better to use the filter directly in SQL? Or maybe use it like this:

```
var listResult = myService.spGetAllData(param1,param2).where(...).ToList();
```

In this case does it load all the data into the memory and then search for that or when I user 'where', it loads just the filtered data?

Comment: Procedural code like stored procedures is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I use Ms Sql server

Comment: Yes, this is very bad for performance. LINQ doesn't query anything. The provider translates the LINQ query into an SQL query. `Contains` maps to `LIKE '%something%'` which can't take advantage of any indexes. The server will be forced to check all records before returning the matching ones. It won't be fixed if you write SQL directly either. If you *really* need to search for strings in the middle of fields you should use full text search

Comment: Thank you very much @Panagiotis Kanavos. It's not really important to search the string in the middle of fields. Actually I'm connecting the result to Datatables jquery and do the search and sort and..  in server side. Then I will change it to filter directly in the procedure.

Comment: What *do* you want to do then? No stored procedure is going to run faster - a stored procedure is just a script with some special handling. 
 It won't make the query run faster. `LIKE '%x%'` performs the same no matter who sends the query. If you want to search for a string at the start, use `StartsWith`, ie `LIKE 'x%'`. Anything else will be slow

Comment: Actually my table is not so big (about 30.000 records) and I think Like works OK for that. Another table I have which will be big in the future and I will use Full text search for that. Thanks

Comment: Stored procedures aren't composable, i.e. they just return the result. Anything that happens after that doesn't affect the size or shape of the SP's result set. So both alternatives load all data into memory. The only difference is that the first alternative creates a redundant intermediary list. If you really want to improve performance you should parametrize the SP to receive a string it can use internally in a `LIKE` clause. Then the result set will actually be reduced.

Comment: Thank you @Gert Arnold. My qiestion is that when I use "var listResult = myService.spGetAllData(param1,param2).where(...).ToList();" , it will load all dataset from SP to client device memory and then use filter on it or just the filtered data will be load to the cliend device memory?

Comment: What was not clear in *both alternatives load all data into memory*?

Comment: I like to know that it loads all data in server memory by demand or in client device memory?